# fragment with fixed buttons

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

[image]

[image]

i want to make (log in / sign up ) buttons fixed in its place and the edit texts is in fragment
how can i do that ? i have done fragment part but i couldn't make the (log in / sign up ) buttons fixed in its place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### STEP-1

Create activity_main.xml which contains

1. Login and Signup Textvies or Button
2. A framelayout or any other layout as a container to be replace by fragment
3. Button to submit form (login or signup)
4. Text view mentioning OR
5. Imageviews or buttons to reference to Gmail and Facebook

activity_main.xml will look like this. **Its just as an example you can customize as per your requirments**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:weightSum="2">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/loginBtn"
                android:text="Log In"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/signupBtn"
                android:text="Sign Up"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_below="@id/header"
            android:layout_above="@id/submitBtn"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/submitBtn"
            android:text="Log in"
            android:layout_above="@id/ok"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ok"
            android:text="OK"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_above="@id/footer"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/footer"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/google"
                android:background="@color/disable_state_color"
                android:src="your_google_img"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/facebook"
                android:background="@color/disable_state_color"
                android:src="your_facebook_img"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

### STEP-2

now you have to create two xmls one for login view (fragment_login.xml) and one for signup view (fragment_signup.xml)

fragment_login.xml will look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:hint="username"/>

    <EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:hint="********"
        android:inputType="textPassword"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/forget_pwd"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Forget Password?"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_signup.xml will look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:hint="email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:hint="username"
        android:inputType="text"/>
    <EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:hint="********"
        android:inputType="textPassword"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/confirm_password"
        android:hint="********"
        android:inputType="textPassword"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

### STEP-3

In your onCreate() of ActivityMain replace container by FragmentLogin

```
public class ActivityMain extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button loginBtn,signupBtn;
    FragmentLogin fragmentLogin ;
    FragmentSignUp fragmentSignUp ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        fragmentLogin = new FragmentLogin();
        fragmentSignUp = new FragmentSignUp ();


        loginBtn= findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);
        signupBtn= findViewById(R.id.signupBtn); 
        
        
       getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,new 
       FragmentLogin(),"Fragment_Login").commit();

     loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,new 
           FragmentLogin(),"Fragment_Login").commit();
                }
            });

    signupBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,new 
           FragmentSignUp(),"Fragment_SignUp").commit();
                    }
                });
            
         }
}
```

### STEP-4

Create your FragmentLogin and FragmentSignUp

**FragmentLogin**

```
public class FragmentLogin extends Fragment
{
    View fragmentView;
    
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
       return fragmentView;
        }
```

**FragmentSignUp**

```
public class FragmentSignUp extends Fragment
{
    View fragmentView;
    
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_signup, container, false);
       return fragmentView;
        }
```

Hope you will get the basic idea of the implementation

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you don't want the login signup button to be replaced with a fragment?

Just put a fixed button in the activity and replace only the changing part with a fragment.